# Change tint color of disabled button won't work

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIButton` which is disabled. This `UIButton` has a image as an icon next to it. I reckon since it's disabled the tint color of the image is grey.

I've already tried to set the button in storyboard to custom and changed it tint color there, which didn't work.

I also tried the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var drivenKmDisplay: UIButton!

let color = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 22/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)

func setDrivenKm(drivenKm: Int) {
        drivenKmDisplay.isEnabled = false
        let string = String(drivenKm) + " km"
        drivenKmDisplay.setTitle(string, for: .disabled)

        let icon = UIImage(named: "timeline")!
        drivenKmDisplay.setImage(icon, for: .normal)
        drivenKmDisplay.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        drivenKmDisplay.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -15, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        drivenKmDisplay.tintColor = color
    }
```

Comment: You can configure the `textColor` of `UIButton` for enabled/disabled state not the `tintColor`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to subclass your button to change the `tintColor` when you enable/disable your button.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            tintColor = isEnabled ? .blue : .red
        }
    }
}
```

And to make sure the image in your button changes to your desired tint color, set the rendering mode of your image to `alwaysTemplate`. You can do this in code or in your Assets catalogue.

```
let icon = UIImage(named: "timeline")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

You will also need to make sure your button doesn't adjust the image when it's disabled.

```
drivenKmDisplay.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

After iOS 15, you can use [UIButton.Configuration.attributedTitle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/3750779-attributedtitle) and set the foreground color of the attributed string, like this:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
        var config = button.configuration
        config?.attributedTitle = AttributedString(NSLocalizedString("Title", comment: ""),
                                                         attributes: AttributeContainer([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: button.isEnabled ? UIColor.white : UIColor.red]))
        button.configuration = config
    }
```